# Можно ли использовать шаблонизаторы в теле цикла в шаблонных строках?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Пользуюсь следующим отрывком кода для вывода на страницу какой-либо информации на основании json-массива с данными:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.some-element').append(`
    <ul>
        <li>${data[i].object}</li>
    </ul>
  `);
}
```

*На деле структура и иерархия намного сложнее. Пример приведён для наглядности*

Могу ли я использовать в шаблонных строках шаблонизаторы? Например:

```
$('.some-element').append(`
    <% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %><li><%- user %></li><% }); %>
    <div>
        <span>${data[i].some_another_data}</span>
    </div>
`);
```

Comment: да в целом кто вам мешает определить шаблон `var tpl = "<li>[title]<li>"` а потом делать `var row = tpl.replace("[title]", item.title)`. Но вообще существуют и js-шаблонизаторы, недавно тут был вопрос про старый JqueryTemplates вроде, который потом мигрировал в другую библиотеке

Comment: @teran что-то совсем не понял, как я могу использовать это в шаблонной строке.